# HTML list split into equal sized chunks in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list with 8 items as this:

```
<ul>
  <li>List Item 01</li>
  <li>List Item 02</li>
  <li>List Item 03</li>
  <li>List Item 04</li>
  <li>List Item 05</li>
  <li>List Item 06</li>
  <li>List Item 07</li>
  <li>List Item 08</li>
</ul>
```

With this list, I want to Keep a fixed width space in between item 04 and 05. And first four items should be align to right of that space and last four to align to left as below image I attached.

[image]

I tried it something like this:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-right: 10em;
}
```

It seems ok for me, but one thing is when the list have 4 or 6 items then it should group 2 or 3.

Can anybody tell what would be the solution for this. Its good if I have `CSS` only solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Just add in another `<li>` with no content inside and give it a class. Add `width:10rem` and possibly some height to it through the class name. All you have to do then is make sure that `<li>` is always in the middle of the group. That way, you don't have to even rely on nth selectors

Comment: @AshleyBrown, Thanks for your suggestion. but in this case I can't use empty `<li>`, because this list generating from a CMS.

Comment: if you can use javascript in your page it is possible to add custom class easily to each <li> after calculation the length of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its interesting!

Need find the middle one to do something without use js.

So i use odd and even to split in half, then use pseudo-element to become the middle one.

see below.

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    li{
      width: 10em;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(odd) {
      order: 0;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(even) {
      order: 2;
    }
    ul::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 10rem;
      order: 1;
    }
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
  </ul>
```

=============================================================

JS

```js
    let num = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    let half = num.length / 2;
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    num[half].parentNode.insertBefore(li, num[half])
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    li{
      width: 10em;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    li:empty{
      border: none;
    }
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
  </ul>
```

================================================

JQ

```js
var li = $('ul li');
    $($('<li>')).insertBefore(li[li.length / 2])
```

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
    }

    li {
      width: 10em;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    li:empty {
      border: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Its great, if we can get items in correct order. Can you tell me how it use JS for this?

Comment: Thank you very much. Its work nicely. One thing Can you help me to code above `js` in `jqery`? `var half = $('ul li').length/2; `

Comment: var li = $('ul li');
$($('<li>')).insertBefore(li[li.length / 2]);

Comment: Hello @donkey, I need to add `css` class for last `<li>` of first chunk and first `<li>` of second chunk as `left last` and `right first`. Can tell me how to do it in jQuery?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq/ i think eq could work, $('ul li').eq(li.length / 2) and $('ul li').eq(li.length / 2 - 1) then change className.